# Symbol "represented by" from quantum mechanics

Tags: math-operators, relation-symbols

The symbol I'm referring to is a standard equal sign with a dot right above it.
I've looked around, but cannot seem to find the LaTeX code for the symbol used by Sakuri to represent operators in his Quantum Mechanics text.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the philosophy of "teach how to fish" and auto-copying a similar previous answer by me, if you go to go to [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) and draw it:

[image]